# Resolving a macro reference within a remote PROC SQL (SAS)

Tags: sql, sas, proc

I've a lot of trouble with referencing to a variable in a remote sessions, within a remote session.

What I'm trying to achieve is a dynamic date query. At this moment the script works fine with the static WHERE statement. However, everything I tried to make a reference to a macro variable, it failed one way or another.

This works:

```
WHERE SDD LIKE '2018-09%'
```

But this doesn't:

```
WHERE SDD LIKE '2018-"&monthn."%'
or
WHERE SDD LIKE '2018-"monthn"%'
or
WHERE SDD LIKE %str(%')2018-&monthn.%str(%')
```

All suggestions are appreciated

---

This is more or less all the relevant code:

```
*-------------------------------------------------------------------;
* LOGIN TO zOS                                                      ;
*-------------------------------------------------------------------;

%let    zos =   ********;
signon  zos     userid=&userid. password=&passw.;

*-------------------------------------------------------------------;
* PREPARE LOCAL VARIABLES FOR TRANSFER TO REMOTE                    ;
*-------------------------------------------------------------------;

%SYSLPUT MONTHN =   &monthn;    /* MONTHN = 11 */

*-------------------------------------------------------------------;
* OPEN CONNECTION, DOWNLOAD FLIGHTS, CLOSE CONNECTION AND SIGNOFF   ;
*-------------------------------------------------------------------;

rsubmit;        /* REMOTE COMPUTING START */

    %PUT &MONTHN;       /* GET LOCAL VARIABLES */

    ----
    Many lines of settings up the 
    wintel/sql connection
    ----

    %SYSLPUT MONTHN =   &monthn;

     rsubmit;

        %PUT &MONTHN;       /* GET LOCAL VARIABLES */

        proc sql dquote=sas;
           create table TKLM1WINTEL as
              SELECT *
              FROM   tables

              WHERE SDD LIKE '2018-"&monthn."%'
              /* WHERE SDD LIKE '2018-09%' */

         PROC download data=TKLM1WINTEL out=DBFILE;
         RUN;

     endrsubmit;

endrsubmit;     /* REMOTE COMPUTING END */

signoff;
```

Comment: What happens if you give the remote macro variable a different name than the local one? For example, `%SYSLPUT monthn_remote = &monthn;`

Comment: Why are you using single quote characters instead of double quotes? Especially after going to the trouble in your PROC SQL statement to make sure that SAS will interpret double quotes normally instead of taking them to mean name literals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I just figured it out myself with a little help from this [source](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Resolving_a_macro_variable_within_single_quotes).

The correct WHERE statement is as follows:

```
WHERE SDD LIKE %unquote(%str(%')2018-&monthn.%%str(%'))
```

Comment: Why not just double quote character instead of single quote character?  Are you actually using explicit pass-thru to code in some other system's SQL implementation?

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work.

```
data abc;
input id sdd $8.;
datalines;
1 2018-091
2 2018-081
;

%let month =09;
proc sql;
select * from abc
where sdd like "2018-&month.%";
```